# Emailing with cygwin and bash, getting authentication error

Tags: windows, bash, email, cygwin

Im kind of new to cygwin, and i have overtaken some code written by an old colleague. The code has worked for 6 years but now i get an error.

In bash i write the following to test to send a mail:

```
echo | email -s "hello" foppa.forslund@gmail.com
```

and i get the error message:

```
email: FATAL: Smtp error: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials w18sm297820lfl.168 - gsmtp
```

The settings in my email.conf file

```
SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'  
SMTP_PORT = '587'  
USE_TLS = 'true'  
SMTP_AUTH = 'LOGIN'  
SMTP_AUTH_USER = 'soderforsprojektet@gmail.com'  
SMTP_AUTH_PASS = 'mypassword....'
```

From gmail instructions

```
Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server  
smtp.gmail.com  
Requires SSL: Yes  
Requires TLS: Yes (if available)  
Requires Authentication: Yes  
Port for SSL: 465  
Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587
```

I have logged in to the account using a browser with the account info stated above, from the computer i want to use bash on. There i can send and recieve email.

Im running

```
Windows 7 Enterprise, service pack 1.   
Bash 4.1.10(4)-release  
Cygwin 1.7.16(0.262/5/3)
```

Please help me find the problem...

Comment: Allowing less secure access in the google account settings solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Allowing less secure access in the google account settings solved the problem